# How to update only a few rows using SqlDataAdapter without deleting existing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, sqldataadapter

I have a table in an SQLServer DB which has a large number of rows. When there is updated data, I want to update the DB accordingly, but only a few rows at a time. My program (Azure Function, to be exact) runs periodically and won't keep track of the state (changed/unchanged) of the data.

I use an API to retrieve **recently updated data only** and save it into `DataTable newData`.
If I just use `SqlDataAdapter.Update(newData)`, then the whole DB is deleted and only the rows in `newData` are inserted. But what I want is that the rows in `newData` are updated into the DB without deleting anything.

Actually I can already do this by retrieving all the existing data, merge the `newData` with it, then use `Update`, as in:

```
DataTable existingData = APIUtil.GetData(tableName);
existingData.Merge(newData);
adapter.Update(existingData);
```

However this is very inefficient because even when I want to update only 3-10 rows, I still have to transfer and hold in memory 15k rows in `existingData`.

Also, if I did this by building a SQL command then I'd only have to execute a few commands, but building that SQL command with `StringBuilder` etc would kill the meaning of using `SqlDataAdapter`. So these are unreasonable methods.

I want to know if there is a method in ASP.NET Core 2.1 C# to update a few rows in the DB, updating  but must not delete existing data. I'm not obliged to use `SqlDataAdapter`. As unseemingly as it sounds, I couldn't find an article on the Interwebs instructing how to do this.

UPDATE: I have tried the following methods without success.

Method 1: Marking the `RowState` of rows in `newData` as `Modified`

```
newData.AcceptChanges();
foreach(DataRow row in newData){
    row.SetModified();
}
adapter.Update(newData);
```

Result:

`Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.`

According to various sources, this happens when you try to update a row that no longer exists in the DB. I guess as I force the rows to be `Modified`, the adapter didn't know which row in the DB to associate with the row in the `newData`.

Method 2: Merging `newData` with empty `DataTable`

```
DataTable existingData = APIUtil.GetData(tableName, schemaOnly: true);
existingData.Merge(newData);
adapter.Update(existingData);
```

Result:

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint...`

The reason is, `Merge` command added new rows to `existingData`, so the rows copied from `newData` has `RowState == Added`. `Update` then, seeing that, tried to `INSERT` those into the DB. But there are already rows in the DB that has that exact set of Primary Key (I specified it because I want to `UPDATE`) thus the error message above.

I guess my best chance is to build my own `UPDATE` SQL and `ExecuteNonQuery`. `SqlDataAdapter` somehow freaking failed to do a task so simple.

Comment: Frankly, `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable` are ancient technology that *you shouldn't be using* in $currentYear$ - any ORM would make short work of this - EF would be a reasonable starting point

Comment: Thansk for the enlightment, I didn't think those were that old. However, replacing all existing code t o write anew with another approach doesn't sound like a proposable solution in a company